# Can I describe a very sexual scene which is needed to identify a movie?

Tags: discussion, identify

There was a movie I watched many years ago, and I don't remember almost anything, except for a... very sexual scene (which is very specific, so I think one who watched the movie can identify it by that scene). The scene in itself is very subtle, there was nothing explicit or graphical on it, however describing what happened is certainly entering NSFW territory.

Also the movie is not pornographic, but a kind of comedic drama (and the scene was way lighter and subtler than many things in mainstream series as Game of Thrones, for example).

So, if I ask an [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) question about, how much can I describe the sexual content of it? Is there a rule about what I can and what I can't do? Or in this case should I ask the question in a more appropriated (and 18+) site?

Comment: I don't really know how to answer your question, because I don't want to give you the wrong advice, but thank you so much for having the consideration to ask here first before posting your question +1 :)

Answer (score 20):

<sup>As to the point of identification questions specifically, I'm afraid the community has [decided to no longer support them on this site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49), so your question likely won't be appropriate to begin with. However, regarding your general question about describing a very sexual scene:</sup>

---

First of all, **textual descriptions are much less problematic than pictorial ones** to begin with. So the question of NSFW should already be out of the way, if that even *is* a problem to begin with. If you're worried about your boss not just seeing the images on your screen but actually *reading* the tiny little letters on it, maybe you shouldn't browse movie sites at work. ;-)

As to the matter of sexuality and sexual descriptions in general, the emphasis is that **it shouldn't be tasteless or overly indulgent**. But from both the way you describe the scene *and* the way you came to meta first in order to gather feedback, I would assume that your description of the scene will likely be totally fine.

We *are* legally a 13+ site here, but that doesn't mean anything sexual is off-topic. Afterall, we're discussing films here that (together with the questions about them) exhibit *way* more serious and problematic themes than a "subtle" sex scene and prohibiting any kind of discussion of sexuality here would hinder many serious film discussions. Just remember to **keep things "tasteful and professional"**. So no, there's no *explicit* and clear rule about it, other than neither being inconsiderate of the professionality of the site nor being overly protective of the sensitive ears of little 8-year old Timmy, since neither is he allowed to register on this site, nor is it our responsibility to protect him from the internet. Your meta question suggests that you're mature enough to find a good balance, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually have started to write a question, so I was able to remember a bit more things about the movie; most of them are at "I guess" level and not certain, but maybe they can help to filter a bit. About the scene, I tried to be the most "boring" and technical when describing it, even using euphemisms to avoid naming things whose name are obviously sexual. I'll still think a bit more if is worth to ask the question (thankfully I'm asking from home, so no boss problems :) )