# How can I find the title of a movie from just a description or image?

Tags: discussion, faq, identify

I **need to find the title of a movie or TV-show**, but I only know part of its story and/or descriptions of scenes and characters. I might happen to know who acted in it or even have some images from it.

However, **this site [doesn't serve identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49)** anymore so it won't help me solve this directly. But how can I get my movie identified still? Are there any external resources I could consult? And if yes, how can I optimize the results I get therefrom?

Comment: As suggested [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4088/49). Feel free to contribute to this.

Answer (score 33):

First of all, there is a site within the Stack Exchange network which still accepts such questions:

- [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) requires the work to contain distinct science fiction, fantasy, or other speculative fiction content. You can consult their meta for guidelines on [how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/23386).

Then there are also some other Q&A sites working similar to SE where you can just provide a description and ask for a movie:

- [**I Remember This Movie...**](https://irememberthismovie.com/)
- [**NameThatMovie?**](http://namethatmovie.org/)
- [**Filmfind**](https://filmfind.co/)
- [**Reddit's /r/tipofmytongue**](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/) (be sure to read the rules sidebar first!)
- [**What is my movie?**](https://www.whatismymovie.com/)
- [Criticker.com](https://www.criticker.com) has a [**Help me name that movie**](https://www.criticker.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=17&sid=401cc87387d72326bb5d62d3d377e503) forum

If you are working from different information than a verbal description, there's also other less Q&A oriented ways to find your movie/TV-show:

- [**Google image search**](https://www.google.com/imghp) lets you search directly for matches to a given image, for when you have a visual representation of either a scene from the film or an actor whose name you'd like to know.
- So does [**TinEye**](https://www.tineye.com/)
- [**QuoDB**](http://www.quodb.com/) might be useful if you only have a specific quote or part of the dialogue you remember.
- [**IMDb's Advanced Search**](http://www.imdb.com/search/) lets you combine a variety of types of information from IMDb catalogs to create extremely specific searches. You can fill in (with the information you have) as many optional fields as you can to narrow the search results.

Comment: This is a first start. If you have similar links, feel free to add them. If you have different, maybe more procedurally oriented, guidance, you might also post it as a new answer.

Comment: Here we are 2 years later, and these suggestions don't really make up for the disappearance of that feature in Movies SE - except maybe reddit where similarly as SE one user can belong to several communities without having to create new accounts. The websites suggested also have way less users than SE does and terrible UI/UX. I don't accept these as alternatives.

Comment: You don't have to. Feel free to add others that work better for you.

Comment: Does any of these allow refining queries with additional criteria or restrictions? Allow for "not" criteria (i.e. certain words not used synopsis)? Allow searching the scripts? Allow for criteria such as "number of words in title"? "number of main protagonists"? "gender of main protagonist"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to identify movies or TV shows with a [Speculative Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_fiction) theme (Sci-Fi, Fantasy, Horror, Superhero Fiction, Alternate History, Utopian and Dystopian Fiction, Supernatural Fiction, and the like), you may want to ask your question on our sister site [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), which allows identification questions for Speculative Fiction works. Please make sure to read their [identification guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957) before posting. You can also browse the [list of questions there tagged [story-identification] and [movie]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification%2Bmovie?tab=Votes) or [[story-identification] and [tv]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification%2Btv?tab=Votes) for some examples of how to format your question and what kind of information to provide.

Relevant Science Fiction & Fantasy SE meta posts:

- [Would non-horror Speculative Fiction be on-topic for this site?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/537/7957)
- [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/7957)
- [Does "Fantasy" include the supernatural? What about horror?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3368/7957)
- [Are questions about alternate history on or off topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/7957)
- [Are comic superheroes considered sci-fi?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/7957)