# Should a link to the FAQ post for list of external sites be added to the identification close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, identify, close-reasons

The current close reason for identification questions goes like,

> Identification questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49) for additional details.

Although, this reason refers to the FAQ post regarding discontinuation of ID questions. However, folks coming to our site for identification services are really lost and don't know where to get their questions answered as we had entertained those questions for a long time. There are also comments under those questions regarding the sites which still support ID questions. We have [a meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/27264) listing such sites.

So, just like Recommendation Question Close Reason, **should we add a link to that meta post containing list of external sites into the ID close reason**?

Proposed wordings can be

> Identification questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49) for additional details. You can also refer to the sites mentioned [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/27264) for identification services.

Answer (score 3):

As the guy who (AFAICT) links to that meta post the most frequently, I'd been considering proposing this exact thing myself. IMHO, there's not much point in having that list if we're not going to actually refer people to it. And since (again, AFAICT) the number of ID questions we're getting isn't really going down all that much, we can definitely benefit from having that signpost to point users in the right direction.

I whole-heartedly support this proposal.

Comment: It's going down quite a bit actually. I'm not sure you remember how many we got before abandoning them, but it wasn't 1 per day.