# Can I ask what a movie is based on scene fragments?

Tags: support, scope

I'm trying to track down a sci-fi movie that I saw as a kid but I only remember a few bits and pieces (no title, no actors). I wanted to post this as a question to the main Movies & TV QA but I noticed that the "identify-this-movie" tag is no longer allowed.

Would my question be on-topic for this site with some other tags or not at all? (I'm not trying to ask the question as a matter of game; I'd like to find the movie in question and watch it again if possible - the few scenes that I recall left quite an impression.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid no, not really. It seems you're about to ask a classic film identification question, which, as you already noticed correctly, [*have been deemed off-topic*](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49) on this site. The *tag* being prohibited is just a consequence of this, using other, ultimately inappropriate, tags will likely not help you there.

This is, however, not necessarily the end of your journey, even if I'm afraid we can't directly help you. But [this related meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/49) and its answers might offer some external resources for you to find what you're looking for. In fact, if the specific film is really science-fiction you could try your luck on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), which, as of now, still serves identification questions.