# My post got deleted without any explanation or feedback

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Earlier today, I asked a question on this stackexchange site. It might not have been a suitable questions, for many reasons that more knowledgeable people here will presumebly enjoy detailing. However, it was deleted. I received no message concerning the question. No feedback at all. I cannot search for it. It does not appear in my history.

So now, my question is: what is the preferred feedback mechanism for newbies like me to learn from their mistakes in this situation?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/108582/last-week-tonight-with-john-oliver link for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question was closed because questions asking to identify specific movies, TV shows, or episodes are off-topic here, and have been for about two years now. It's unfortunate that nobody left a comment to that effect before the question was closed, but comments on downvotes/closevotes aren't mandatory, and for good reasons.

You would have received *some* feedback in the form of this close message, that I can see about [your (now-deleted) question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/108582/46980):

[image]

What must have happened, though, is that the question was deleted before you even knew it was closed, let alone had a chance to read that message.

In my experience, off-topic questions get closed and deleted *very* quickly on Movies.SE, which is both a blessing and a curse; a blessing because we don't have low-quality questions sitting around, and a curse because it leads to situations like this one, where people are left wondering where their post went.

As for your actual question:

> what is the preferred feedback mechanism for newbies like me to learn from their mistakes in this situation?

Do exactly what you just did: post a question on Meta, calmly explaining the situation and asking what was wrong with your question and how/whether it could be improved. Someone will come along and help you out.

Comment: Can't people see their own (recent) questions when they are deleted?

Comment: They can, yeah, but OP noted that he couldn't find it, and I can't remember where the "recent deleted questions" section is either.

Comment: Thanks . As a side question, where does this type of question belong if not here?

Comment: As a side-note: Earlier, I was accessing the site through the Android app, which did not let me check the status of the question. Now, following the link you provided, I can actually access the deleted question. I was not aware of that (i.e. the fact that the web interface is more permissive than the app), which actually renders my question somewhat mute.

Comment: The app hasn't been supported for a while, something I wish was made more apparent to its users. It's better to access the website directly via your phone's browser, it's fully responsive. As for where you can go to ask these questions, [this Meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/46980) has a list of possible places.

Comment: Thanks very much!