# WHY? Why are you deleting my posts?

Tags: support, specific-question

Why is my question being deleted? I am simply just asking a question about a movie I am trying to watch. All I am ASKING is what is this movie?

Answer (score 8):

Your first question was closed. The reason is that this community has decided that it doesn't exist to answer identification questions like that.

You can see this from the description of the close reason:

> Identification questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to this meta post for additional details. You may also check this list of external identification resources.

I'm genuinely sorry about that - but we've decided that this is an 'off topic' question. The list of on and off topic questions can be found [in the help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Your second question was closed and deleted as a copy of the first.  I'm sorry, but we have informed you that the question isn't going to be answered here.  Repeating the question isn't going to override that.

Someone even commented this to help you out:

> Please don't repost closed questions; they'll just get closed a second time. I truly am sorry, but we can't help you. The list linked to in the close message of your first question is the best we can do for you. –

We have pointed you to some [resources that may help you identify the movie](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image).