# Where to ask about movies from my past that I can't remember?

Tags: discussion, identify

When did this tag [identify-this-movie] become off topic? Where should we go now to ask about movies we can't remember?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the title of a movie from just a description or image?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image)

Answer (score 3):

It has been around 3 years since ID questions became off topic.

You can find some suggestions for [how to identify a movie in this question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image)