# Does this community still accept questions trying to identify films from plots?

Tags: discussion

I have a film I remember from years ago but cannot remember the name of it, and all Google searches bring me to films that are similar, but not the one I remember.

I looked at the "identify this move" tag and all the questions are closed, so does that mean this type of question is no longer welcomed here?

Comment: If it's science fiction related, just go over to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/, that seems to be where many of the identification questions go now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for checking.  Your guess is correct, Identification questions are now off topic and will be closed.

We do have a meta post to try and give you [resources to identify your movie](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the quick answer. I'll see if any of those resources work but I fear maybe not as it was not a very well known movie and the plot has been redone in a few more recent ones that got more popularity so may end up finding those instead!