# Identifying an actor

Tags: discussion, identify

I know identification questions for movies are off topic now.

What about Identifying an actor or actress?

I need to find about an actor in a movie. If I post a question now, is it get answered or closed?

Comment: if you want to find an actor/actress in a movie, a quick google search will tell you who exactly he/she is, providing you know the movie name. if not, then this is a breaking point (identify movie(off-topic, so this'll get removed)->identify actor(won't be able to come this far) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All identification questions are off-topic for main site.

The close reason is clear.

> Identification questions are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/48608) for additional details.

This includes identifying actors also. Even if it gets an answer, it will be closed and will be deleted later.

Comment: If I recall correctly, actor ID questions were off-topic even before movie ID questions were made off-topic.