# Is asking which movie did it first identifying a movie?

Tags: discussion, scope

I [asked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/103067/what-is-the-first-movie-to-use-a-vcr-or-recording-device-to-trick-an-adversary) a question about which movie was the first to use a playback device to trick an adversary.

It recieved one downvote (later upvoted) but no answer as of right now.

Does it violate the [post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Buing-support-for-identification-questions) about asking for identification of movies?

Will my question be closed for being off topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it violate the [post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Buing-support-for-identification-questions) about asking for identification of movies?
>
> Will my question be closed for being off topic?

No and no. [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) questions are not identification questions and are on-topic. If they were banned, the tag description would contain the following message, jsut like the other ID tags:

> NO LONGER ON TOPIC. DO NOT USE. IDENTIFICATION QUESTIONS WILL BE CLOSED AS THEY ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED.

Furthermore, identification questions are closed *very* quickly here, usually in a matter of minutes. As of right now, it's been six hours, and nobody has voted to close your question. I don't believe anyone will.

I can't say for certain why your question was downvoted. Users are under no obligation to explain their downvotes, for a variety of reasons. However, it would not have been because your question is off-topic; downvotes are not close votes. My only guess is that the downvoter decided your question was "not useful", which is a valid downvote reason. (For the record, I do not believe your question is "not useful"; it could be interesting to see how quickly Hollywood began integrating video technology into its plotlines.)