# Why is a question about a performer's acting history an "identification question", or more generally why is it off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I've [asked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/115741/has-jon-stewart-done-impersonations-of-conspiracy-theorists-before) if a certain TV comedy performer has done certain kind of act (in a show) before.

It was closed as an ["identification question"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions) (with that link). Why is it an identification question? Or more generally, off-topic?

Comment: You're asking us to *identify* if an episode exists where this has (or not) happened...hence **identification**. Regardless, this is, IMO, both too broad and trivia so even more off-topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D: so if I ask if John Wayne has played in any non-Westerns, is that an identification Q too? Or is it just too broad and trivia?

Comment: Yes and easily searchable.,